# Imageview looks like mapview

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, android-image

I have a image `(resolution 8328x3987)`. And I want to load that image in my app with `zoom controls` for better viewing.

As we all know that `Android` will not load large images directly on device (like in my example). So `Android` system suggested us to scale down the image to load large images. I have tried this and scale my image upto four times as:

```
options.inSampleSize = 4;
```

Using this way my image will displayed on screen, but when I `zoom-in` the image then this image becomes unreadable (text becomes very blurry), this is because, maybe I scale down the image before showing?

But when I see that image in to device's default gallery app `(Android Lollipop, Photos app)`, then this image looks like a `mapview` (only visible portion is readable and outside is blurry, and when I move the image then visible area becomes readable) when I zoomed in at max level. So my questions is:

Is `Android lollipop` added any new way to load large files that looks like `mapview`?

If not, then do you have an idea how that apps do this or any example?

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the sample size of an image that big will not work at all.(very very bad resolution and memory consumption)

I suggest you to divide image to tiles and recycle the views just like map views do.

[This](https://github.com/luminousman/TiledImageView) library may help you. Or you can do it your way too.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am going to try this library now.